How to set global stylesheet for github pages via _config.yml?
I have some github pages using one of the supported themes (the pages are built automatically by github, not locally). I would like to tweak the css globally, without adding import statements to each page.
I created a style sheet in my project with this path: /assets/css/nbstyle.css, and then added this to my _config.yml:
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
    values:
      stylesheet: "css/nbstyle.css"

But that seems to be getting ignored.
What is the correct way to specify a custom style sheet via _config.yml? And will that just over-ride the theme's CSS, or will both stylesheets get imported?
(Or is this not even possible?)

Studying the docs and examples a little more closely, I figured it out.
Simply create this file: /assets/css/style.scss
Then start that file with:
---
---

@import "{{ site.theme }}";



And then add the desired additional (s)css there.
Nothing needs to be added to _config.yml.
